# Query slow, possible optimization

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization, reporting-services

I have the following situation: I have like 16 queries in a report, which all use nearly the same `SELECT` statement in the beginning:

```
SELECT 
    sereresystem.registrationtime,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,sereresystem.registrationtime),0),120) AS [Day], 
    CAST(datepart(YEAR,sereresystem.registrationtime) AS CHAR(4))+' / KW '+CAST(Datepart(ISO_WEEK,sereresystem.registrationtime) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [Week],
    Datepart(m,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,sereresystem.registrationtime),0)) AS [Month],
    CAST(datepart(YEAR,sereresystem.registrationtime) AS CHAR(4))+' / '+CAST(Datepart(q,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,sereresystem.registrationtime),0)) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS [Quarter],
    Datepart(year,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,sereresystem.registrationtime),0)) AS [Year],
    COUNT(sereresystem.caseid) AS [Total]
FROM sereresystem
    INNER JOIN sereregeneral ON sereresystem.caseid=sereregeneral.caseid
    INNER JOIN sereresperou ON sereresystem.caseid=sereresperou.caseid
WHERE sereregeneral.inpcha IN(@Inputchannel)
    AND sereresperou.assrol IN(@Assigned_Role) 
    AND sereresystem.registrationtime BETWEEN @Starttime AND @Endtime
    AND sereresystem.referencenumber=sereregeneral.renure
GROUP BY sereresystem.registrationtime
```

I need the values for day, week, month, quarter and year to dynamically group after these Values in SSRS.
The Problem I have now, is that the report is damn slow. Is there a possibility to shrink the processing time for these 5 Date-select statements?

-edit- now the complete query

Comment: The issue will be the `FROM` not the `SELECT`

Comment: how many rows is this query returning? How many of those end up in the final report? Do you aggregate the results?  -- In short, can you post the entire query? The part you are showing is unlikely to be causing your problem.

Comment: The query returns depending on the dates choosen (starttime and endtime) and depending on the choosen Format 8day, week etc.) So theres´s a possibility to geht about 365 rows per year (choosing day) or 1 Row (choosing year)

Comment: Why do you need to run the query sixteen times? Couldn't you run it once, getting the superset of data, and then divide/filter that in your report?

Comment: I don't think it is a performance bottleneck, but it won't be helping that you are doing all your formatting in SQL. 5 of the 7 columns are just registrationtime expressed in a different varchar format. You could do all the same formatting in SSRS (you would need a column for ISO_WEEK since as far as I am aware this is not a valid option in an SSRS expression). There is also redundant calculations in your select, e.g. using `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)` to get the first day of a month, then using `DATEPART(Q, ...` on this date. This is the same as `DATEPART(Q, Date)`.

Comment: Running the same query 16 times in one report will cause all sorts of dead locks.  Collect your subset by creating a veiw, then do your aggregations.  A function might also work here.

Comment: Check the [ExecutionLog2 view](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) to see whether your problem is with Data Retrieval, Processing, or Rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You should define "damn slow" and what your expectation / requirement is.

Assuming the 16 queries are not identical, then running them as separate datasets will usually be faster than combining them.  This is due to the parallel architecture of modern servers, SQL and SSRS.

I would review the table indexing - if you are not sure then a separate index on every column referenced after the FROM clause would be a good start.